# Не отображается RecyclerView в фрагменте

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

У меня почему-то не работает RecyclerView. Скорее всего это связано с какими-то особенностями при работе из фрагмента, потому что у меня больше нет идей.

Я специально распарсил ArrayList в TextView, чтобы убедиться что не передаю пустой лист пустой. Ошибка все таки была, но и после ее отладки ничего не заработало.
После этого заменил свой адаптер на 100% рабочий код с ютуба, чтобы исключить свои возможные ошибки. Но все равно Recycler оставался пустой.

Итого: я не знаю, в чем ошибка. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

**Код получения и передачи листа тексту (*test()*) и ресайклеру (*inflateRecycler()*):**

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    val accessToken = activity?.getSharedPreferences(PREFFILE_AUTH, MODE_PRIVATE)
        ?.getString(PREFNAME_ACCESS_TOKEN, "")

    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                errorRoot.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                test.visibility = View.GONE
                messagesProgress.visibility = View.GONE
                messagesRefresh.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

    }

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(handler) {

        val responseCoroutine = async {
            val requestResponse = getConversations().getRequest(accessToken!!, false)
            return@async CallToVK().call(requestResponse)
        }
        val response = responseCoroutine.await()
        val parsedResponseCoroutine = async {
            return@async getConversations().parseResponse(
                response,
                activity?.applicationContext!!
            )
        }
        val parsedResponse = parsedResponseCoroutine.await()

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            test(parsedResponse)
            inateRecycler(parsedResponse)
        }
    }

    messagesRefresh.setOnClickListener {
        errorRoot.visibility = View.GONE
        test.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        messagesProgress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        messagesRefresh.visibility = View.GONE

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(handler) {

            val responseCoroutine = async {
                val requestResponse = getConversations().getRequest(accessToken!!, false)
                return@async CallToVK().call(requestResponse)
            }
            val response = responseCoroutine.await()
            val parsedResponseCoroutine = async {
                return@async getConversations().parseResponse(
                    response,
                    activity?.applicationContext!!
                )
            }
            val parsedResponse = parsedResponseCoroutine.await()

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                test(parsedResponse)
                inflateRecycler(parsedResponse)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun test(array: ArrayList<MessagesListModel>) {
    var text = ""
    for (i in 0 until array.size) {
        text += "title: " + array[i].title + "\nphoto: " + array[i].photo + "\npreview: " + array[i].preview + "\n"
        if (array[i].hasUnread) {
            text += "countUnread: " + array[i].countUnread + "\n"
            if (array[i].mutedUnread) {
                text += "mutedUnread: true\n"
            } else {
                text += "mutedUnread: false\n"
            }
        }
        if (array[i].online == 1) {
            text += "online: desktop\n"
        } else if (array[i].online == 2) {
            text += "online: mobile\n"
        }
        text += "\n"
    }
    test.text = text
    messagesProgress.visibility = View.GONE
}

fun inflateRecycler(gotList: ArrayList<MessagesListModel>) {

    recyclerMessages.adapter = CommonMessagesAdapter(gotList)
    recyclerMessages.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)
    recyclerMessages.setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

**Код Adapter'a:**

```
class CommonMessagesAdapter (array: ArrayList<MessagesListModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CommonMessagesAdapter.CommonMessagesViewHolder>() {

var list = array

class CommonMessagesViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val photo: ImageView = itemView.profilePhoto
    val title: TextView = itemView.textName
    val preview: TextView = itemView.textPreview
    val unread: TextView = itemView.textUnreadCount
    val unreadMuted: TextView = itemView.textUnreadMutedCount
    val online: ImageView = itemView.onlineIcon
    val onlineParent: FrameLayout = itemView.onlineBg

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CommonMessagesViewHolder {
    return CommonMessagesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_message_list_item,
        parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CommonMessagesViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val item = list[position]

    holder.title.text = item.title
    holder.preview.text = item.preview
    holder.photo.load(item.photo) {
        crossfade(true)
        placeholder(R.drawable.profile_placeholder)
        error(R.drawable.profile_placeholder)
    }
    if (item.hasUnread) {
        if (item.mutedUnread) {
            holder.unreadMuted.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.unreadMuted.text = item.countUnread
        } else {
            holder.unread.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.unread.text = item.countUnread
        }
    }
    if (item.online == 1) {
        holder.onlineParent.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else if (item.online == 2) {
        holder.onlineParent.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.online.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_online_mobile_12)
    }

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

fun commonSetList (al: ArrayList<MessagesListModel>) {
    this.list = al
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

}

Если нужно еще что-то - скину. Заранее спасибо!

**Дополнение: разметка:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/fui_white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/messages_messages"
        android:textColor="@color/fui_black"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/messagesProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messagesRefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_outline_28"
            android:tint="?colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="#dfdfdf" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:textColor="@color/fui_dark_grey" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/errorRoot">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_error_outline_56"
        android:tint="@color/fui_red" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/messages_error_loading"
        android:textColor="@color/fui_black"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerMessages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:listitem="@layout/view_message_list_item"/>
```

**Решение:**
В моем случае оказалось, что ресайклеру просто не хватало места для отображения, а код был правильным. Если на примере моей разметки: сверху над ресайклером есть TextView, который позже (в функции *test()* становится гораздо массивнее, чем просто "Loading..." и загромождает весь фрагмент, а значит у ресайклера не остается места для отображения. Надеюсь, кому-то поможет моя ошибка.

Comment: НУ в адаптере вроде все ок. Хорошо бы макет показать. А сам фрагмент вообще открывается с RecyclerView?

Comment: @sergei-buvaka Сам фрагмент 100% открывается, ибо из всего что есть на экране не видно только ресайклер. Вопрос обновил - добавил разметку

Comment: Проверьте сеть. Проверьте ваш адаптер с мокнутыми данными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Скорее всего это связано с какими-то особенностями при работе из фрагмента, потому что у меня больше нет идей.

Это не так.Тут все тоже самое, никаких особенностей нет.
Что конкретно не так? Сказать сложно, возможно ошибка в коде есть, но на первый взгляд ее не вижу. Очень много мест где что-то могло пойти не так. Учитывая что тут сетевые запросы.
Я бы посоветовал вам 3 шага для отладки.
Во-первых закоментить сетевую часть и захаркодить небольшой лист со своими данными.
Во-вторых поставить логи в метод onBindViewHolder, чтоб убедится что адаптер работает и идет связь item  и holder
B  так же не стоит завывать Layout inspector. Убедится что RecyclerView в видимой части экрана и нормального размера. А то вдруг он высотой в 1dp 
Также чтоб убедится, то что RecyclerView вообще виден, можно более простым способом, поставить в layout  ему android:background вырвиглаз цвет.